# Randomizer picks a number from the vector and delete it

Tags: c++, vector, random

So, program picks this number from the vector, it's actually a sequence {1...n} and I want  to print out and delete random number from it. However, everytime program prints out {n...1} sequence.
Example: Vector(1,2,3,4,5) => program picks random number 4 => Vector(1,2,3,5) => random number 1 => Vector(2,3,5) and until Vector(). So, program will print (4,1,...). 
In case of this program, it always prints out (5,4,3,2,1) for Vector(1,2,3,4,5).

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    rand();
    int toReturn;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of tickets: ";
    std::cin >> toReturn;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> nums;


    for (int i = 1; i <= toReturn; ++i)
    {
        nums.push_back(i);
    }

    int choice=0;
    bool checked=0;
    while (nums.size() > 0)
    {
        bool inVector=0;
        choice = rand() % toReturn + 1;

        while(inVector == 0)
        {
            choice = rand() % toReturn + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)
            {
                if (choice == nums[i])
                {
                    inVector = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                     inVector = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Why not check the ticket " << choice << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Did u do it right?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> checked;
        if (checked)
        {
            nums.erase(std::remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), choice), nums.end());
        } 

        else
        {
             continue;
        }
    }
    if (nums.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "You checked all tickets!!!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would be glad if you leave any suggestion to code refactoring

Thanks everybody for help, completely rewrite my program with std::random_shuffle this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
int main()
{

    int toReturn;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of tickets: ";
    std::cin >> toReturn;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> nums;


    for (int i = 1; i <= toReturn; ++i)
    {
        nums.push_back(i);
    }
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
    int choice = 0;
    std::shuffle(nums.begin(), nums.end(), g);

    while (nums.size() > 0)
    {
        bool checked = 0;
        choice = 0;
        std::cout << "Why not to check " << nums[choice];
        std::cout << std::endl << "Did you do it right?";
        std::cin >> checked;
        if (checked == 1)
        {
            nums.erase(std::remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums[choice]), nums.end());
        }
        choice++;
    }


    std::cout << "You checked all tickets!!!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is similar to a lottery pick, then, 1. Fill a vector with the domain of numbers. 2. shuffle the vector. 3. resize the vector to the no. of choices. 4. that's it. sort them if you want after, but that will give you N random picks from a sequence of some fixed (and reasonably small) domain sized M, where M >= N. Regarding your code. ask yourself what `inVector` is even used for, and more important, whether you should `break` when you discover equivalence, thereby further calling out whether it is even useful. What happens to it during the *lifetime* of the for-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your for loop. Even if it finds that a number eg. 1 is present in [1 2 3 4 5] and sets

```
inVector = 1
```

it will carry on and check next numbers in the nums and set eventually

```
inVector = 0
```

unless it's the last number.

You have to terminate the loop just when the condition is met eg.

```
if (choice == nums[i])
{
    inVector = 1;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should change this line

```
if (choice == nums[i])
```

to this:

```
if (choice <= nums[i])
```